# Assistance writing Regex in JavaScript for telephone number validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been tasked with writing an `if/else` structure for a JavaScript regex telephone validation checker and I am running into issues. My constraints and formats are as follows:

- Only accept digits (Minimum 4 to Max 40)
- 4 digit phone extension, for an extension, which will be formatted into "ext ####"
- 10 digit phone number, which will be formatted via substitution into "(###) ###-####"
- 11 digit phone number, which will be formatted via substitution into "(###) ###-####"
- 14 or 15 digit phone number, which will be formatted via substitution into "(###) ###-#### ext ####"

I am trying to strip off all characters except for numbers, then process it through the regex. When I move the `x = x.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');` above the `if (x.length == 4) {` and below `var x = newValue;` it does not work.

What I have thus far that is working is the following:

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading) {
    // If the newValue is empty, return
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }
    // If the newValue is the same as the oldValue, return
    if (newValue == oldValue) {
        return;
    }

    // If the newValue is a completely new value and does not equal the previous value, perform the following validations
    if (newValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
            var x = newValue;

            if (x.length == 4) {
                // If the length of the value is 4 characters, place "ext " in front of the number
                x = x.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
                x = x.replace(/(\d{4})/, 'ext $1');
                g_form.setValue('u_phone_number', x);
            } else if (x.length == 10) {
                // If the length of the value is 10 characters, format the number as (###) ###-####
                x = x.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
                x = x.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
                g_form.setValue('u_phone_number', x);
            } else if (x.length == 11) {
                // If the length of the value is 11 characters, format the number as (###) ###-####
                x = x.replace(/[^\d\s]+/g, '');
                x = x.replace(/(\d{1})?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($2) $3-$4');
                g_form.setValue('u_phone_number', x);
            } /*else {
                alert('Please enter a phone number of 4, 10, or 11 digits, no other characters and it will be properly formatted.');
                g_form.setValue('u_phone_number', '');
            } */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I move the x = ... above the if (x.length == 4)... it does not work."  Then I think you need to check what `x` is at that point. Also, an console error or incorrect result is more helpful than "It does not work"

Comment: True, I should have provided a console.log() statement. Let me work on that and get back to you.